# run spark progress on windows 10 give error can not find wintuls.exe

Tags: hadoop

I run a spark progress on windows 10 with eclipse which will write file on hadoop system. when I run the code it give the error like "can not find the winutils.exe".
so I down load the wintuils.exe from a net https://letstalkspark.blogspot.fi/2016/02/getting-started-with-spark-on-window-64.html and configure it. 
then I run the code again. above issue is not there by give anther problem like

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:522)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.client.ClientWrapper.<init>(ClientWrapper.scala:171)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:162)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.executionHive(HiveContext.scala:160)
at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.<init>(HiveContext.scala:167)
at org.apache.spark.sql.CarbonContext.<init>(CarbonContext.scala:34)
at org.carbondata.examples.util.InitForExamples$.createCarbonContext(InitForExamples.scala:42)
at org.carbondata.examples.CarbonExample$.main(CarbonExample.scala:26)
at org.carbondata.examples.CarbonExample.main(CarbonExample.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: ---------
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createRootHDFSDir(SessionState.java:612)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.createSessionDirs(SessionState.java:554)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:508)
... 8 more
```

so I continually run the command "wintuitls.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive" it give following error, then I can not get the answer from google.

```
winutils.exe chmod 777 /tmp/hive 
ChangeFileModeByMask error (3): ??????????
winutils.exe chmod -R 777 /tmp/hive
GeFileInformantionByName error (3): ????????
```

Comment: I am new for spark and hadoop, who can help for this. thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Create tmp/hive folder in the drive where winutils.exe exists.
This solved same problem in my system.